# Do you know if there is anyway to turn off the iPod Touch pinging NTP server?

Tags: ios

We have a bunch of iPod Touch devices deployed in an Enterprise environment, they are pinging NTP server and it looks like it is for accurate time keeping. Is there anyway I can turn off the devices pinging the NTP server? We are hearing from the network guys that pinging is slowing the network down. The real problem we are trying to solve is the WIFI Drop, for some reason these devices are dropping 5 to 8 times a day and the network guys are saying that this is due to the iPod Touch devices pinging the NTP server. Is that traffic so high to cause WIFI drops?

Comment: How often do they connect to the ntp server? is it ping to an ntp connection?

Comment: Why would they be pinging ntp? ntp doesn't need pinging, it just needs ntp... it's its own protocol, & should expend as much network effort as dms'ing google.com

Answer (score 1):

Easy. Go to Settings > General > Time & Date > Turn off Set Automatically.

This will allow you to set the time on the iPod manually AND stop it from pinging Apple's NTP server (time.apple.com).

More on that [here.](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203483)